# attribute of short code not working in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, parsing, attributes, themes, shortcode

I am using [scope](http://themeforest.net/item/scope-agency-business-wordpress-theme/952938) theme. The attributes of the shortcodes is not working in live site. Though its working in local and one of another linux server. I tried uploading the plugin and its not working as well. For example if I have a shortcode [toggle title="This is the title"]This is the description[/toggle], shortcode is parsed properly but the attribute title is not parsed.

Can anyone suggest me, what the problem might be. I have disabled all the plugins and tried to use the shortcodes but it did not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Deactivate and then re-activate the plugin.

Comment: thanks .. already done but did not work for me

Comment: Have you checked the functions.php file of the theme, maybe even registering the shortcode? Example: `add_shortcode('sermon', 'sb_shortcode');`

Comment: Tried this one but did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try accessing the function that the shortcode is pointing to and passing the variable directly to that function:

```
the_shortcode_function("This is the title");
```

Just call this function where you need the shortcode output.